# How can make map using gmapping_demo with turtlebot simulation stage

Tags: ros, gmapping-demo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear friends
I try to make map using gmapping_demo with turtlebot simulation stage.

When I run gmapping_demo.launch  it give me "No device connected....."

I know that turtlebot_gazebo can make map and this is the [link for the tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_gazebo/Tutorials/indigo/Make%20a%20map%20and%20navigate%20with%20it)

in my case
1st I run

> roslaunch turtlebot_stage turtlebot_in_stage.launch

then I run

> roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241506/how-can-make-map-using-gmapping_demo-with-turtlebot-simulation-stage./) by [momar82](https://answers.ros.org/users/14996/momar82/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2016-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your problem is that `roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch` attempts to launch the node for a physical 3D sensor, such as a Kinect or Asus Xtion, as well as the gmapping node. If you look at the file [gmapping_demo.launch](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/blob/indigo/turtlebot_navigation/launch/gmapping_demo.launch) you can see it includes `3dsensor.launch`.

The tutorial instructs you to use `roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo gmapping_demo.launch` because Gazebo/Stage is simulating your sensor, so it only needs to start the gmapping node, which you can see [here](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_simulator/blob/indigo/turtlebot_gazebo/launch/gmapping_demo.launch).

So try running `roslaunch turtlebot_stage turtlebot_in_stage.launch` as you were, then `roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo gmapping_demo.launch`, and it should work fine.

---

Originally posted by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) with karma: 606 on 2016-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [momar82](https://answers.ros.org/users/14996/momar82/) on 2016-08-11**:
THANKS for your fast answer.

what I figure-out that turtlebot_stage represent a navigation with know map and we can test our path plaining using turtlebot_stage.